# Is wudhu done after gusl?

Tags: practical-islam, wudu, ghusl

Is **wudu** done after **gusl** (bathing)? I have this question because you wash your whole body during gusl including hands, face, legs, ears and all other parts.

Answer (score 1):

```
                                   In the name of Allah
```

> Is wudhu done after gusl?

To the best of my knowledge, solely a kind of Qusl (Qusl al-Jenabah) would be sufficient instead of Wudu. In other word, you don’t need for wudu after doing Qusl-a;-Jenabah. But after doing other Qusls, you ought to take wudu. (According to majority of Shia Marja’s)

---

**Reference:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa5379)
- [masaell110.mihanblog.com](http://masaell110.mihanblog.com/post/18)

Answer (score 1):

Well Sunni madhabs made a lot of rules for ghusl, but the most important part of it is that water should reach the [whole body](http://sunnah.com/muslim/3/66).

**Short answer**

A short Answer for your Question could be find for Ghusl al Janabah (as an interpretation of Verse  ([5:6](http://legacy.quran.com/5/6)))

> And if you are in a state of janabah, then purify yourselves وَإِنْ كُنْتُمْ جُنُبًا فَاطَّهَّرُوا

in this hadith narrted by um al-mu'minyn 'Aisha (May Allah be pleased with her) which was qualified as once [da'if](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/1/107) and once as sahih in [Jami' at-Tirmdihi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/1/104)  and hassen in [Sunan ibn Majah](http://sunnah.com/urn/1102540) and [Sunan an-Nasa-i](http://sunnah.com/nasai/4/35).

So far this answer is in totally agreement with the one of our brother @ali-علی and the shi'a Marji's, but i would like to add some more information.

**Some details**

- Now this Answer is valid for a Ghusl wajib this means ghusl Janabah, ghusl from menstruation etc.. But if this is a ghusl which is not fard/farz (for example ghusl for friday or 'id prayer ...) some scholars say this ghusl isn't valid for prayer even if you had the intention.
- An other point if you during your ghusl have lost your tahara/purity you should do wudu after the ghusl!

**Note** that our Messenger used to do wudu as a part of ghusl (see my 2nd reference)!

Here are two fatwas on the mater [Arabic](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/128234) and [English](http://islamqa.info/en/5032)!

And Allah knows best!