# Does a shower followed by wudu count as ghusl?

Tags: ghusl

I have heard that ghusl can be just a shower that has to cover all parts of your body, your head, nostril, etc.

If I first take a shower, with niyyat to do ghusl, and then I do wudu', does this count as ghusl?

Comment: See for example [How to perform ghusl?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2131/how-to-perform-ghusal-ghusl?), [If I don't perform ghusl according to sunnah would my ghusl be valid?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/if-i-dont-perform-ghusul-according-to-sunnah-would-my-ghusul-be-valid?), [Is wudu done after ghusl?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28018/is-wudhu-done-after-gusl?) and [Is my ghusl valid (Seee details)?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30156/is-my-ghusl-valid-please-see-details?)

Comment: With wudhu after ghusl you will be one clean Muslim

Answer (score 1):

There are three fards in Ghusl.

1) To wash mouth with water as it should reach all the parts internally. From lips to the base of the throat. If not fasting gargle. If there is anything stuck in between teeth such as a piece of meat, paan, beetle nut; it should be removed before Ghusl or the Ghusl will not be completed.

2) To wash inside of the nose with water. Water should be pulled hard enough all the way to the soft part of the base of the nose. If there is any dry phlegm inside the nose it must be cleaned and if the nose is pierced water should be forced into the hole or the Ghusl will not be completed.

3) To wash the body once from head to the bottom of feet. The water must pour over the body. Every strand (hair) and skin of the body must get wet. Even if a single strand or a small portion of skin is not washed the Ghusl will not be completed.

So if you did all of these three in a shower, there is no need of wudu.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help]. Could you provide any evidence for considering these points as fard? (Also see [answer]).

Answer (score 0):

Intention is very important for any action. So you make the intention (niyyah) of ghusl and then pour water all over your body and head or stand under shower to have all parts of the body get wet, then that will be accepted as ghusl or Islamic bath.

You don't need to do wudu afterwards as part of ghusl.

However, if you also have the intention of wudu while doing ghusl and rinse your mouth and put water in nostril etc. -- then you have done both ghusl and wudu.

But if you did not have the intention of wudu while doing ghusl, then you need to do wudu after ghusl for doing salah or touch Quran mushaf etc.